# reuse cache in all junit test cases

Tags: java, junit

we have multiple test cases which loads the data into cache and run the test case .the test cases runs fine but the when we ran all test cases once its takes lot of time as the cache is loaded every time for each test case.Is there any way to load cache once and then use the cache across all test cases.

One way of doing that is put all the test cases in one class but it defeats the purpose as the result will be difficult to analyze(There are around 5-10 test method in each class and there are around 30 test classes so the report which gets generated will be very large and not organized).
I tried using test suite but the cache is getting shutdown after each test case as it runs them one by one.

Comment: General observation - while it may take some take to create your cache, creating it for each test will help ensure your tests can't pollute one another. Unless it's a read-only cache..?

Comment: ya it can pollute ...but we are also running test cases individually ...the final run which runs all test cases will be just before deployment in test env which makes sure everything is working fine

Comment: Is it possible to clone/copy your cache? Perhaps then you can create the cache once and copy it for each test.

Comment: See also [How to cache a JUnit class field between runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654528/how-to-cache-a-junit-class-field-between-runs-with-parameters).

Answer (score 6):

You can create abstract class that will be the base class for all your test cases. The cache should be initialized into this class and stored in its static member. Then all tests should use this cache.

Alternative solution is to implement your custom test runner that will manage the cache. Then you have to mark all test cases that need cache using annotation `@RunWith` and pass the test runner class there.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine, +1 for suggesting an abstract parent class.

Comment: that looks good..can you please explain how do i use @RunWith or if you can refer an example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Test Suite which contains the @BeforeClass method that initializes the Cache and then add all your test cases there. This allows for easy addition of more test classes afterwards as well. Remember to put them in the correct order if that matters. Top suiteclass runs first.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
TestClass1.class,
TestClass2.class
)}
public class TestSuiteClass {
    @BeforeClass
   public void initCache() {
       //Your init code here.
   }
}
```

Some useful links: 
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html
http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/runners/Suite.SuiteClasses.html

Slightly more comprehensive example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) would satisfy your needs.

> Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup
>   (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the
>   independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization.
>   Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes
>   it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class

You can make use of this within a superclass and the subsequent sublasses may simplify your code/test organisation.

Comment: "*One way of doing that is put all the test cases in one class but it defects the purpose as the result will be difficult to analyze*" <-- not sure this will work for the OP.

Comment: Yes. I don't quite understand the above statement, and I'm not sure how the analysis relates to the code structure

Comment: i am using before class for loading the cache...but this is the case for every test case ,so its doing the same thing...can we add beforeclass in test suite then we can have cache loading only once