# How to cache a JUnit class field between runs with @Parameters

Tags: java, junit

Lets assume the following JUnit test class:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTestClass {

    private ExpensiveObjectToCreate myObject;

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
                { "parameter1" },
            { "parameter2" },
                };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
    }

    public MyTestClass(String stringParameter) {

        myObject = new ExpensiveObjectToCreate(stringParameter);
    }

}
```

Is there any way for me to create the expensive object just once for every parameter set? I say this because JUnit creates a new test class for every test it needs to run. This means that the expensive object is NOT created 2 times, but actually 4 times (2 parameter sets x 2 tests). This gets even worse when we have many test methods.

Also, sending the expensive object as a parameter is not a solution for me because my scenario is a little bit more complicated (I create the expensive object in JUnit rules).

Comment: have you tried @BeforeClass and creating the expensive object there?

Comment: @OliverWatkins That will require making the expensive object static, not sure if that would work.

Comment: I tried that but @BeforeClass is invoked just once per test class. I need something to be invoked once for every parameter set.

Comment: this post might have something useful in it : http://blog.varunin.com/2011/07/running-selenium-tests-on-different.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just roll out a custom cacher in your test case class, which caches the instance created per parameter and returns the same instance on further invocations.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Test {

    private static ExpensiveObjectCacher cacher; //instance which caches parameter instance
    private ExpensiveObject myObject;

    public Test(String value) {
        this.myObject = cacher.get(value); 
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass(){
        cacher = new ExpensiveObjectCacher();
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
                { "parameter1" },
            { "parameter2" },
                };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test1(){

    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test2(){

    }
}

//caching for test cases. 
class ExpensiveObjectCacher{
    private Map<String, ExpensiveObject> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ExpensiveObject>();

    ExpensiveObject get(String value){
        ExpensiveObject instance = map.get(value);

        if(instance == null){
            instance = new ExpensiveObject(value);
            map.put(value, instance);
        }

        return instance;
    }
}

class ExpensiveObject{
    public ExpensiveObject(String value) {
        System.out.println("Instance created: " + value);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
Instance created: parameter1
Instance created: parameter2
```

Comment: Check out the suggestion I have provided.

Answer (score 3):

You could work with a static `Map` from the parameters (here a simple string) to instances of `ExpensiveObjectToCreate`.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public fnial class MyTestClass {
    private static final Map<Parameter, ExpensiveObjectToCreate> MAPPING = new HashMap<>();

    private ExpensiveObjectToCreate myEOTC;

    public MyTestClass(String stringParameter) {
        myEOTC = getEOTC(new Parameter(stringParameter));
    }

    private static getEOTC(Parameter parameter) {
        ExpensiveObjectToCreate eotc = MAPPING.get(parameter);
        if (eotc == null) {
            eotc = new ExpensiveObjectToCreate(parameter.stringParameter);
            MAPPING.put(parameter, eotc);
        }
        rturn eotc;
    }

    private static final class Parameter {
        String stringParameter;
        Parameter(String stringParameter) { this.stringParameter = stringParameter; }
        @Override public int hashCode() { ... }
        @Override public boolean equals(Object other) { ... }
    }
 }
```

However, if you also need to limit the number of expensive objects, you should do more work, for example a cache could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Junit 4:

```
private static  ExpensiveObjectToCreate myObject;
private static String stringParameter = "some text";

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    myObject = new ExpensiveObjectToCreate(stringParameter);
}
```

If Junit 3:

```
private static  ExpensiveObjectToCreate myObject;
private static String stringParameter = "some text";

@BeforeClass
protected static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    myObject = new ExpensiveObjectToCreate(stringParameter);
}
```

In both cases the object will be created once for all the unit tests.

Edit: The String I am not sure where it came from, so I am asuming that the String is the same for all unit tests.

Comment: Where do you get `stringParameter` from?

Comment: @Narendra Pathai True, I edited asuming that all unit test will use the same String.

Comment: @Narenda Pathai The string parameter is passed automatically by JUnit from the data() method annotated with `@Parameters`.

Comment: @Loïc The solution you provided doesn't work for me as I want to create the expensive object just once for every parameter set. `@BeforeClass` is invoked just once for every class (NOT once for every parameter set in the class).

Comment: @Sminon Yes, I realised after. What you really want try to do is to modify an object without re-creating it because of the creation cost. Or you can use a setter, or if it is not the tested class, you can mock it. After you can map object, but then you creating several objects.